# Mysqli bind parameters not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

I'm trying to use prepared statements to enter data in a database. The unprepared statement works but this prepared statement does not. I can't find out why.
Prepared version:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (file_name, upload_by, date, path) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $newstring, $id, $date->format('Y-m-d'), $location);
$stmt->execute();
```

Unprepared version:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO videos (file_name, upload_by, date, path) VALUES ('$newstring', '$id', '
          $date', 'Nominator/$location$newstring')";
  mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

Comment: Correct $stmt-execute(); it must be $stmt->execute();

Comment: while that was wrong. It's still not working.

Comment: Give $date separately and then check. Also add table structure.

Comment: taking `->format('Y-m-d')` off the date worked. I had put it there when trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$stmt-execute();` with `$stmt->execute();`

Also, don't use `date` and `path` in query. Rename them with some other name like `date1` and `path1`.

Update your Query like below that will surely work (Tested Offline):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test2'); 

if ($mysqli->errno) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
exit();
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (file_name, upload_by, date1, path1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $file_name, $upload_by, $date1, $path1);
$date1 = date("Y-m-d");
$file_name = "test.jpg";
$upload_by = "amit";
$path1 = "test";
if ($result = $stmt->execute()){
echo "success";
$stmt->free_result();
} else {
echo "error";
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: have done but still not working. Could one of the variables be causing the issue. `$location = "Nominator/uploads/".$newstring;` that is the location variable which I suspect might be

Comment: Try without date. And show me your connection. You are trying prepared query?

Comment: it was the $date variable causing the issue. Many thanks!

Comment: Also rename date and path variables both in database and your code. I found they are not working.

Comment: Check my updated answer that I have tested offline. It's better if you keep your variable names same as column names in your table.

Answer (score -1):

You are binding your parameter twice, if you are using only ?, don't bind parameter again just execute directly.

```
 //Prepare your query first
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO videos (file_name, upload_by, date, path) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

//Just pass your argument and execute directly without binding the parameter (The parameter is binded already)
$stmt->execute('ssss', $newstring, $id, $date->format('Y-m-d'), $location);
```